# Implement a Raspberry Pi 4 button in C language

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a traffic light when the button is pressed it would change from green -> yellow -> red. However, my button is not working. May I know how to fix the button?

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Define GPIO pin numbers
#define RED_PIN    10
#define YELLOW_PIN 11
#define GREEN_PIN  13
#define BUTTON_PIN 26  // Optional button pin

// Function to set the state of LEDs
void setLEDState(int red, int yellow, int green) {
    printf("Setting LEDs: RED=%d, YELLOW=%d, GREEN=%d\n", red, yellow, green);
    digitalWrite(RED_PIN, red);
    digitalWrite(YELLOW_PIN, yellow);
    digitalWrite(GREEN_PIN, green);
}

int main() {
    // Initialize wiringPi library
    if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing wiringPi\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Set GPIO pin modes
    pinMode(RED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(YELLOW_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN_PIN, OUTPUT);

    // Optionally, set button pin mode
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);

    // Initial state: RED
    setLEDState(1, 0, 0);

    // Traffic light sequence
    while (1) {
        // RED
        printf("RED state\n");
        delay(3000);

        // RED + YELLOW
        printf("RED + YELLOW state\n");
        setLEDState(1, 1, 0);
        delay(1000);

        // GREEN
        printf("GREEN state\n");
        setLEDState(0, 0, 1);
        delay(3000);

        // PAUSE or BUTTON PRESS (Optional)
        if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH && digitalRead(GREEN_PIN) == HIGH) {
            printf("Button Pressed during GREEN state\n");
            // Toggle between GREEN and RED only when the button is pressed during GREEN state
            printf("YELLOW BLINKING state\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                setLEDState(0, 1, 0);
                delay(500);
                setLEDState(0, 0, 0);
                delay(500);
            }
            setLEDState(1, 0, 0);
            delay(1000);  // Increased debounce delay
        }

        // GREEN
        printf("GREEN state\n");
        setLEDState(0, 0, 1);
        delay(3000);

        // YELLOW BLINKING
        printf("YELLOW BLINKING state\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            setLEDState(0, 1, 0);
           delay(500);
           setLEDState(0, 0, 0);
           delay(500);
        }

        // RED
        printf("RED state\n");
        setLEDState(1, 0, 0);
        delay(3000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I set the `digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == LOW`, it will automatically run the logic in it every time it passes through the code.